# WebExtension display secure dialog

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, webkit2-webextension

I want to write a webextension that displays a tiny dialog to obtain some sensitive data from users.  However, I do not what thieves.com to be able to produce a dialog that looks exactly like the one I would be presenting.

Is there any way to do that in any of the common browsers?  One thought would be to put the dialog in the URL bar, which I do not think is possible from a web page.  But is that really impossible from a web page and is it possible using a normal extension?

Another option might be something like the ctrl-alt-delete that used to protect windows.  Have the user type some keystroke that cannot be intercepted by javascript.

Comment: Use a standard UI surface of an extension like the popup (browser.browserAction.openPopup) or the [sidebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sidebarAction).

Comment: I think a side bar could be forged.  popup seems to be the go.